# Interpreting Answer to Lettercountr(str) in Coderbyte

Tags: javascript

Very much a noob, hope this question isn't hopelessly stupid.

Have been working my way through the Javascript problems on Coderbyte, and have been hopelessly stuck on below lettercount exercise :

http://www.coderbyte.com/CodingArea/GuestEditor.php?ct=Letter%20Count%20I&lan=JavaScript

Have found following solution online (which works):

```
 function LetterCountI(str){

   var x=str.split(" ") 
   var count=0; 
   for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++)//getting the word
     var word=x[i]
     for(var j=0; j<word.length; j++)//getting the letter
      var letter=word[j]
       for(var k=0; k<word.length; k++)//comparing word
         if(j !== k) { /* verify that the letter being pased is not literally the same as in the higher for loop */
           if(letter===word[k]){
           count=count+1; 
              if(count>1){
               return word;  
           }
        }
     }   
  return -1;
}
```

I'm clear on everything through until that last "return -1". I understand why it's needed, but it seems awkward the way it's placed. Shouldn't it be included as an "else" alternative in the if chain somehow? Anyt attempt on my part so far in integrating that though has so far broken the program.

Am I right in thinking this program basically tries to run the if chain first, and in case its conditions aren't met THEN it goes to the "default" of returning -1?

Thanks in advance for your time if anyone has any insight in to this!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be placed in an `if` due to the fact that the `if` is inside a `for`. This is a pretty typical way to structure this sort of algorithm. It essentially runs through the `for` loop to find a result, if it is not found, return a default. Another way to structure it so that there is only one `return` statement could be (Slightly less efficient):

```
function LetterCountI(str){

   var x = str.split(" ");
   var count = 0;
   var res = -1;
   for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {//getting the word
     var word=x[i];
     for(var j=0; j<word.length; j++) {//getting the letter
       var letter=word[j];
       for(var k=0; k<word.length; k++) {//comparing word
         if(j !== k) { /* verify that the letter being passed is not literally the same as in the higher for loop */
           if(letter === word[k] && res === -1) {
              count=count+1; 
              if(count>1){
                 res = word;
              }
           }
         }
       }
     }
   }
   return res;
}
```

Comment: Thanks neelsg, that helps clarify it!